# Clipping two 2D triangles

Tags: math, graphics, geometry, computational-geometry, polygons

I know that there are efficient polygon clipping algorithms out there (e.g., Maillot, Vatti, Greiner-Hormann). However, these algorithms work for arbitrary polygons and although they fit my case, it seems to me that using such general algorithms for a simple case like mine is an overkill.

What I have is two 2D triangles (see figure below) that I want to clip the one against the other. Searching in the web didn't find anything apart from general polygon clipping algorithms.

[image]

**Q:** Is there a specialized algorithm for clipping two 2D triangles?

Answer (score 2):

For two convex shapes the traditional approach is just Sutherland Cohen, but with more or fewer flags.

E.g. in your case:

- blue A is outside red AB but inside the other two red edges; give it code 100;
- blue B is the same; give it code 100;
- blue C is outside red BC but inside the other two so give it code 010.

Starting from A:

- code is non-zero, don't include blue A in the output;
- looking at edge blue AB, the binary AND is non-zero so don't consider for output;
- code for blue B is non-zero, don't include in output;
- codes B and C AND to 0 so XOR* them. Gives 110. So find intersections of blue BC with edges red AB and BC, add them to the outpyt list;
- code for blue C is non-zero, don't include in output;
- codes for blue C and D again indicate to intersect with BC and AB so do so and add to output.

(* or OR them; we've established they share no bits in common so it makes no difference — I think XOR is a little more descriptive in saying that you're looking for differences)

Answer (score 2):

Two methods, effective for convex polygons, are described [here](http://www.iitg.ernet.in/rinkulu/compgeom/slides/cvxpolyintersect.pdf) - Hoey's algorithm and O'Rourke's algorithm.
(I've used O'Rourke's one for convex quadrilaterals)

Answer (score 1):

Just hints for optimization.

The complete discussion of which edges intersect and which vertexes belong to the final outline only depends on the algebraic areas of the triangles formed by a vertex of one triangle (A) and an edge of the other (B).

There are 9 such triangles, hence 9 areas and 9 signs. Anyway, the three triangles built with the same vertex of (A) have areas that sum to the area of (B), and only 9 - 3 + 1 = 7 areas need to be fully computed.

In addition, an intersection point between two edges is computed from two areas, using a formula like t= S / (S - S'), where t is the parameter along an edge.

So a completely unrolled algorithm can be written as a decision tree of depth 9 (using the 9 signed areas), with every leaf (512 of them !) generating a sequence of vertexes/intersections. There can be at worst 6 intersections.

Comment: There might be more than 512 leaves, because each one of those determinants may be positive, negative, *or zero*... so at most, 3^9 = 19683 leaves. (Of course, using symmetries of the problem, most of those might be removed).